# Word for "way of dressing?"

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> I wonder if his [...] has something to do with his craziness.

The only word I could think of was *attire*. But I think attire only refers to what the person is wearing now; not to the *way* he or she usually dresses.

Comment: I'd probably use *wardrobe* there. It refers to the clothing in his current rotation.

Comment: I usually use *fashion*, since it's specifically for, well, fashion style.

Comment: *Way of dressing* is fine, as are *wardrobe* and *attire* (the statement can refer to his attire generally; it does not necessarily mean what he is wearing now).

Comment: @Raestloz Fashion is not the same as style :-)

Comment: @andy256 exactly. Fashion is specifically for... uh, well, fashion: the way of dressing, while style is much more general

Comment: @Raestloz If you're saying that style transcends fashion, then we agree :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Style](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/style)**

> ... a form of appearance, design, ... elegance or refinement of manners, dress, etc.

While usually positive, it can also be applied in a negative sense, as in

> I don't like his style. He looks like a banana.

Another phrase would be *dress sense*.

Answer (score 1):

[Look](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Look) can  refer to a fashionable  or specific way of dressing :

> - (Clothing & Fashion) style; fashion: the new look for summer, his new look is quite unusual.
> - A distinctive, unified manner of dress or fashion: the preferred look for this fall.

Source: TFD

Answer (score 0):

aesthetic could be used here.

Example: Her particular aesthetic is more suited to the Goth scene. Or you could use the word aesthetic to further modify fashion, as in "fashion aesthetic."